# Turn Associative Array into simple array

Tags: php

I have and array of arrays:

```
$initial_array = Array ( [0] => Array ( [Site Name] => Sydney [Product Name] => Admission [Total Sales Value] => 3989.98 [Total Sales Quantity] => 570 ) [1] => Array ( [Site Name] => Sydney [Product Name] => Admission Comp [Total Sales Value] => 0.00 [Total Sales Quantity] => 195 ))
```

That I want to use PHP to turn into a simple array as follows:

$translated_array =

```
Array ( [0] => Sydney,Admission,3989.98,570 [1] => Sydney,Admission Comp,0.00,195 )
```

I've been playing with the array_values function but cannot seem to get this right, anyone any ideas? 
What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `implode` function to convert the array into comma separated string. Since you want to convert each inner array into a string while keeping the array structure as it is, I have used a loop. You can use another way to reach to each inner array.

You can read more about `implode`[HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Try below

```js
<?php

$final_array = [];

foreach($initial_array as $new_array){
   $final_array[] = implode(',', $new_array)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use implode to change the array values to comma seperated value,

```
 $array_values= [];
 foreach($initial_array as $array)
 {
   $array_values[]=implode(',',$array);
 }
 var_dump(array_values);
```